# Convert ARKit SCNNode's bounding extent

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have an ARKit app that uses plane detection, and successfully places objects on those planes.  I want to use some of the information on what's sitting below the object in my approach to shading it - something a bit similar to the WWDC demo where the chameleon blended in with the color of the table.  I want to grab the rectangular region of the screen around the footprint of the object, (or in this case, the bounding volume of the whole node would work just as well) so I can take the camera capture data for the region of interest and use it in the image processing, like a metal sphere that reflects the ground it's sitting on.  I'm just not sure what combination of transforms to apply - I've tried various combinations of convertPoint and projectPoint, and I occasionally get the origin, height, or width right, but never all 3.  Is there an easy helper method I'm missing?  I assume basically what I'm looking for is a way of going from SCNNode -> extent.

Comment: are you looking for the [`SCNBoundingVolume`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnboundingvolume) protocol?

Comment: Did you use projectpoint on the 4 corners of the bottom plane of the boundingBox? Another option would be to use the boundingSphere. Subtract its radius from the Y component of its center and project the result to 2D. That will give you the center point below the object.